# Searching by nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have a trouble searching by nested field.

For example my document is:

```
{
    "chat": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "id": "61",
                    "text": "some text here"
                },
                {
                    "id": "62",
                    "text": "some62 text62 here62"
                },
                {
                    "id": "63",
                    "text": "some63 text63 here63"
                },
                {
                    "id": "64",
                    "text": "some64 text64 here64"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm searching through messages.text. If I search

```
"text": "some"

{
    "query" : {
        "nested": {
            "path": "messages",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "text": "some"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want output something like

```
{
    "chat": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "id": "61",
                    "text": "some text here"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and not the whole document. I suppose I should use nested property, so messages in chat is mapped as "nested".
Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "That feature is currently not supported by Elasticsearch. You would need to change to parent/child documents in order to get back only the relevant documents." from here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/Y9o9Vz8BT1s